# How to photolyze anything?

Tags: photochemistry

If you have read this question and you thought that what is this stupid question then sorry to ask this question to you. Hey reader if you want to increase one student's knowledge then please answer this. Hey reader please answer this in an easy way. I am only in 10th grade\class.

Comment: Very few people will like this question since it looks like you are asking us to do the work for you. If you have a specific question, or you can narrow you request to certain conditions, then you should have better responses.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find a suitable solvent.
2. Record a UV-VIS spectrum to determine at which wavelength you need to irradiate.
3. Chose the right glassware. For $\lambda$ = 254 nm, quartz is mandatory. Irradiations at $\lambda$ = 300 nm and above may be performed in pyrex.
4. Chose the right light source. For $\lambda$ = 254 nm, use a low-pressure mercury vapour lamp. For irradiations at $\lambda$ around 300 or 360 nm, use low-pressure mercury vapour lamps with specific coatings. Medium- or high pressure lamps typically show much broader emission spectra. For experiments at $\lambda$ = 589 nm, use a sodium vapour lamp.